# Why doesn't Xcode6 see included header files

Tags: c++, opencv, xcode6

I'm trying to build opencv2 as a universal framework.  I am systematically removing the files/folders that I do not need.  But I am running into this issue where the include files are not found.  See the image below:

[image: Lexical or Preprocessor Issue]

The following image clearly shows that the file is indeed there.

[image: includes]

One of the contractors working with us said he had put the include files into the same directory as the source files and rename them according to their file structure but using "." instead of "/" as shown below:

[image: hpp includes with dots]

But that means that I must go through all of the files that include files and change the include statement to use "." instead of "/".  REALLY?

[image: hpp include statement with dots]

Is this true?  Or do we have a configuration set wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup search paths for your target in Build Settings->Search Paths->Header search paths.